# How to make a key for an old Yale padlock

Tags: lock

[image: lock front]

[image: lock back]

I found this old padlock and plan on cleaning it up and using it for decoration. There was no key with it. Is there a way to modify the locking mechanism and fashion a key (even a useless flat edge one) that would allow it to be opened and closed?

Comment: Here’s a video of one that looks like that being opened, so you know what the key will look like. I don’t make this an answer, as the link could go stale: https://m.facebook.com/Thekeyholesurgeon/videos/a-lovey-little-yale-towne-padlock-missing-keys-no-more-in-catalogs-from-1893-to-/240311220503100/

Comment: Can you post a clear photo of the bottom of the lock please?

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's a nice looking lock you've got there, and I'm sure it'll be even nicer once you've cleaned it up.

Since you don't need the key to be functional, go hit up your favorite on-line <s>junk</s> auction site and buy a `Yale` branded key.

- If the blade of the key fits into the lock great, insert it.
- If the blade doesn't fit into the lock, cut the blade off then weld, super glue, epoxy the head onto the slot.

---

If you do need a functional key, either watch some YouTube videos on lock picking to figure out how to get it open or contact a locksmith to have him make you a key.

Comment: OP does want it to open and close, but not picky if a key or screwdriver jammed in the opening.  Think the lock might be struck too tight to open now.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I see that now, @crip659. I read it as "I don't care if it works, because it's just going to be decorative".